# How to remove duplicate data-target children within the parent element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Using vanilla Javascript, how would you remove duplicate data-target children within a single parent element? Is there a way to do this without putting each element into an array then filtering through that array?

**Start**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" data-target="1"></div>
  <div class="child" data-target="1"></div>
  <div class="child" data-target="2"></div>
  <div class="child" data-target="3"></div>
  <div class="child" data-target="4"></div>
  <div class="child" data-target="1"></div>
  <div class="child" data-target="5"></div>
  <div class="child" data-target="6"></div>
  <div class="child" data-target="7"></div>
  <div class="child" data-target="5"></div>
  <div class="child" data-target="3"></div>
  <div class="child" data-target="8"></div>
  <div class="child" data-target="9"></div>
  <div class="child" data-target="2"></div>
</div>
```

**Goal**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" data-target="1"></div>
  <div class="child" data-target="2"></div>
  <div class="child" data-target="3"></div>
  <div class="child" data-target="4"></div>
  <div class="child" data-target="5"></div>
  <div class="child" data-target="6"></div>
  <div class="child" data-target="7"></div>
  <div class="child" data-target="8"></div>
  <div class="child" data-target="9"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In pure JS you could create an array of targets. Cycle every `.child`: if its `data-target` attribute is new then add it to the array, else remove the `.child`.

```js
let targets = [];
document.querySelectorAll('.parent .child').forEach(child => {
  if (targets.includes(child.getAttribute('data-target'))) {
    child.remove();
  } else {
    targets.push(child.getAttribute('data-target'));
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" data-target="1">1</div>
  <div class="child" data-target="1">1</div>
  <div class="child" data-target="2">2</div>
  <div class="child" data-target="3">3</div>
  <div class="child" data-target="4">4</div>
  <div class="child" data-target="1">1</div>
  <div class="child" data-target="5">5</div>
  <div class="child" data-target="6">6</div>
  <div class="child" data-target="7">7</div>
  <div class="child" data-target="5">5</div>
  <div class="child" data-target="3">3</div>
  <div class="child" data-target="8">8</div>
  <div class="child" data-target="9">9</div>
  <div class="child" data-target="2">2</div>
</div>
```

*N.B.* I have added numbers inside `div`s to see the result when running the code snippet.